# Properties of Team Sites and Publishing Sites

Tags: content-type, publishing-site, properties, team-sites

[image: Editable Properties of Publishing Site]I was just checking on the various features and properties of the various types of sites available in SharePoint 2013 and then I came across the **Edit Properties Settings**. In the **Team Site Properties**, the **Content Type Column** wasn't available but was present in the **Publishing Site Properties**.

So is there a possible way to get that option in a Team Site?

[image: Editable Properties of Team Site]

Comment: Can you please give us more explaination ?

Comment: I have added pictures for reference. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can go to List/Library setting and enable content type management from advanced setting of the same.[image]